# Why NSLog print like these?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Line of Code:

```
@interface ViewController (){
IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_FirstName;
IBOutlet UILabel *lbl_LastName;

}

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

lbl_FirstName.text=@"XFirst";
lbl_LastName.text=@"XLast";

NSLog(@"First Name: %@",lbl_FirstName.text);
NSLog(@"Last Name: %@ %@",lbl_LastName.text);

}
```

Result:

```
First Name: XFirst
Last Name: (null) XLast
```

Problem:
  *    Why 2nd NSLog statement print like these?

I know the reason of (null), because i didn't give any reference for the lbl_Lastname in my .xib. But I don't know the reason of print after (null).

Comment: NSLog(@"Last Name: %@ %@",lbl_LastName.text);
Why d0 you have %@ twice? 
Are you trying
NSLog(@"Last Name: %@",lbl_LastName.text);
or
NSLog(@"Last Name: %@ %@",lbl_LastName.text,lbl_LastName.text); ?

Comment: Now only i come to iPhone development. So i trying with fun, i got this result. I dont know about the result of 2nd NSLog statement technically. That why i'm asking. FUNNY gives +10 grades.

Comment: Was not there a yellow warning from Xcode on that line?

Comment: Yes, it gives yellow warning. But its not important now. Please find and tell the reason of NSLog print like that....

Comment: Supplying less arguments than % conversions in the format causes *undefined behavior*, so anything can happen.

Comment: @Martin: Yes, Undefined behaviour; Even we increase the unwanted "%" conventions, the result are varied based on number of "%" conventions.

Comment: @UdanPirappu: If the behaviour is undefined then it does not make much sense to ask for the "why?", because anything can happen. What kind of answer to you expect?

Comment: @Martin I just discussed with yours to know about its behaviour techinically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the next object in memory happens to be the value of "XLast".

What I speculate happens is:

- You create a string: `@"XLast"`
- The program attempts to assign this value to `lbl_LastName.text`, but since `lbl_LastName` is nil, it fails.
- The NSLog correctly prints out the fact that `lbl_LastName.text` is ni, but since you have two `%@`, it also prints out the next object in memory. This happens to be the string: `@"XLast"` that you just allocated.

This is likely undefined behaviour and it may not act the same every time.

Comment: I think you're right. You can make the program crash if you add another `%@` after the second one. But if you declare one more variable, like `NSString *test = @"XTest";`, the third `%@` gets also printed (in my test I get a reference to the view controller...). This is definitely a strange question :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html), it says:

> In format strings, a ‘%’ character announces a placeholder for a value, with the characters that follow determining the kind of value expected and how to format it.

So, probably, it allocates/announces two placeholders for your string already. And, it finds the value for the first placeholder. Found nothing.. Hence, it shows `(null)` and finds a value for the second placeholder and prints it accordingly. This should be the case IMHO..

Answer (score 0):

hey Why you add more than %@ for more than one variable print value like this.

```
NSLog(@"Last Name: %@",lbl_LastName.text);
```

If you are getting null value in console the check your outlet connection

Comment: You Correct. But discuss this, why NSLog print "XLast" in console even  i didnt reference it.

Comment: lol when you compiled your program it will store XLast value in your lbl_LastName.text and print it. if you didnt reference it does't mean that it will not print. it will not show in your view but it will print it

Comment: Then why it print (null) for first "%@". Think of it.

Comment: its giving me warning.you are getting null value because apple fix null value if anyone using more than one %@ for only one variable.why you are going against xcode warning

Answer (score 0):

specifier %@

Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise. Also works with CFTypeRef objects, returning the result of the CFCopyDescription function.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: Please tell me what you observed from these document?